# "As" VS "before" in this context

Tags: conjunctions

In a newspaper article I read a sentence:

> Women **had begun** to outnumber men **as** the *namaz* began at the shrine.

We usually use:

> **(Past simple + as + past sample)**

> **(Past perfect + before + past simple)**

> I had finished speaking to her **before** I got off the bus.

> The light went out **as** I plugged in the charger.

If I use **before** instead of **as** in the newspaper sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with the sentence as it is written.

There is no time gap implied.

It is saying that, at the time time (instant) that the namaz began, women began to outnumber men.

It also implies that, up to the start of the namaz, numbers of men and women were about equal.

Does that help?

Alan.

Answer (score 1):

You may use 'before' instead of 'as' if that's what you mean, but those words mean different things.

In this context 'before' means prior to the event and 'as' means at the time of the event.